# How to use getElementById and addEventListener when not in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have dynamic HTML code in my JS. I would like to add an ID to one of the tags:

```
      content: `
        <p id="openKeyboard">
          If clicked I want to activate event.
        </p>
      `
```

However, I get this message in console:
[image]

```
    const el = document.getElementById("openKeyboard");

    el.addEventListener("click", this.modifyText, false);
```

When I put id="openKeyboard" on an element on the DOM, it works. But not when my HTML is in the JS. How to use getElementById and addEventListener  when not in the DOM?

Comment: Do you need it to happen if that element eventually shows up?

Comment: Yes, please. If paragraph shows up, when clicked, run the function "modifyText"

Comment: Look up event delegation. Jquery handles it

Comment: When/how is your dynamic html rendered? When/how is your event listener added?

Comment: This dynamic html is being fed into a package called TipTap Editor (Prosemirror wrapper).  It will be loaded as soon as the Editor finishes loading. I am using Vue. My Event listener is added in the mounted section (the code is below the console errormessage).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted), you may get it work if calling `getElementById` like this:

```
mounted: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {

    const el = document.getElementById("openKeyboard");
    el.addEventListener("click", this.modifyText, false);

  })
}
```